# Proof of simple divisibility fact

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I want to prove that $a \nmid bc$, and I know that $gcd(a, b) = 1$, then why does it precisely does it suffice to show that $a \nmid c$?

Thanks.

Comment: The contrapositive of $a\nmid c\Rightarrow a\nmid bc$ is $a\mid bc\Rightarrow a\mid c$. There are I think a number of posts that explain how to show this on the assumption of $a,b$ coprime.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. Then we want to show that:

> If $a \not \mid c$, then $a \not \mid bc$.

To do this, it suffices to prove the contrapositive:

> If $a \mid bc$, then $a \mid c$.

Indeed, suppose that $a \mid bc$ so that there is some $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $ak = bc$. Then since $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, it follows by Bézout's Lemma that there exist $s,t \in \mathbb Z$ such that:
\begin{align*}
as + bt &= 1 \\
acs + bct &= c \\
acs + (ak)t &= c \\
a(\underbrace{cs + kt}_{\in ~ \mathbb Z}) &= c \\
\end{align*}
Thus, it follows that $a \mid c$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$